# discovery if ICMPv4 inbound is allowed on firewall

Tags: powershell, batch-file, firewall

Trying to list ICMPv4 Inbound Allowed rule on windows firewall (to process in batch/ps hybrid script)

```
powershell.exe "Get-NetFirewallPortFilter -Protocol icmpv4 | Get-NetFirewallRule | ft enabled,direction,action"
```

This give me about 10 results. How to filter only results which have "Enabled=True" and "Direction=Inbound"?  I am able filter script output by findstr, but shoud be better to do this in powershell.

Comment: As already mentioned in the existing answer, you could pipe into Where-Object: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Get-NetFirewallPortFilter -Protocol ICMPv4 | Get-NetFirewallRule | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -Eq 'TRUE' -And $_.Direction -Eq 'Inbound'} | Format-Table Enabled, Direction, Action"```. However, I'm a little perplexed as to what use the result would be to you. The only way I can see it being useful is if you do not really want to know just that information, and your true intention has been omitted from your question.

Comment: Writing script, which detect actual atatus, and offer ICMP echo reply enabling via netsh. Need first know if icmp reply is not currently alloweb before enabling it duplicitly.

Comment: So you don't need to know all of this information at all, all you needed to do is determine whether there was a single result.

Comment: You are right, but I will offer disabling possibility in future and thus may be good to know how many enabling rules are stored.

Comment: Not really, because there's no way of determining what any of them are with the information you're retrievng. You may as well determine if there is at least one, or count them instead.

Comment: Hmmm, its really not easy. Tried this `netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=all protocol=icmpv4` got following output                                                                                                                          `Deleted 2 rule(s).` but there still remaning about 6 rules filtered by out powershell command :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Where-Object`:

```
powershell.exe "Get-NetFirewallPortFilter -Protocol icmpv4 | Get-NetFirewallRule | Where-Object {`$_.Enabled -eq 'True' -and `$_.Direction -eq 'Inbound'} | ft enabled,direction,action"
```

Comment: when deleted backquotes just before $ character, it does work as expected thanks